# I can't pass the variable why?flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have tried in many ways to pass the variable points but I can not use it in another class below I leave the basic code.the variable in question is points which is located in the pointspage and I would like to use it in cartpage

CartPage

```
class CartPage extends StatefulWidget {
 

  _CartPagestate createState() => _CartPagestate();
}


class _CartPagestate extends State<CartPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {//some code...}
```

PointsPage

```
class points extends StatefulWidget {
  _pointsState createState() => _pointsState();
}

class _pointsState extends State<cubox> {
  int points = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadPoints();
  }

  _loadPunti() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      punti = (prefs.getInt('points') ?? 0);
    });
  }

  _savePunti() async {
    
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('points', points);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { // some code...}
```

the variable in question is points which is located in the pointspage and I would like to use it in cartpage. the cartpage also has a cardmodel I would like to use the points variable to make "purchases" but I can't.

Cartmodel

```
class CartModel extends ChangeNotifier {

  // list of items on sale
  final List _shopItems = const [
    // [ itemName, itemPrice, imagePath, color ]
    ["Avocado", "4", "assets/images/avocado.png", Colors.green],
    ["Banana", "2", "assets/images/banana.png", Colors.yellow],
    ["chicken", "12", "assets/images/chicken.png", Colors.brown],
    ["water", "1", "assets/images/water.png", Colors.blue],
    ["apple", "3", "assets/images/mela.png", Colors.red],
    ["chocolate", "3", "assets/images/broccoli.png", Colors.brown],
  ];

  final List _other = const [
    ["Avocado", "14000", "assets/images/avocado.png", Colors.orange],
    ["Banana", "2", "assets/images/banana.png", Colors.blueGrey],
    ["chicken", "12", "assets/images/chicken.png", Colors.red],
    ["water", "1", "assets/images/water.png", Colors.blue],
  ];

  // list of cart items
  final List _cartItems = [];

  get other => _other;

  get cartItems => _cartItems;

  get shopItems => _shopItems;

  // add item to cart
  void addItemToCart(int index) {
    _cartItems.add(_shopItems[index]);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // remove item from cart
  void removeItemFromCart(int index) {
    _cartItems.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // calculate total price
  String calculateTotal() {
    double totalPrice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
      totalPrice += double.parse(cartItems[i][1].toString());
    }
    return totalPrice.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to access `points ` when `navigate ` or from `any place`?

Comment: I would like the points accumulated in the pointspage to be used as "credit" within the cartpage, i.e. when the user clicks a button like "buy" the points necessary for the purchase are subtracted, I've been trying for months

Comment: As in your code using `sharedPreference` is a good idea , but what is the problem with  get points from   `sharedPreference`?

Comment: when I try to import the variable it doesn't let me use it it says it doesn't exist for pointspage but in reality it exists and it is used inside the pointspage, it doesn't let me use it to create a points subtraction method

Comment: can you share the error.

Comment: "Il getter 'points' non è definito per il tipo 'pointspage'. "

Comment: when i try to use it outside of pointspage

Comment: You can  use it by `prefs.getInt('points')` in any page ,points  in pointspage  is not `a global variable`.

Comment: where should i add prefs.getInt('points')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access a variable from another class ,make the variable  static and use it by calling `ClassName.VariableName` in the other class.

```
//global value 
int globalPoints = 23;


class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({super.key});
  // variable inside first class 
  static int counter = 1;

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

```
class MyWidget2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget2({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget2> createState() => _MyWidget2State();
}

class _MyWidget2State extends State<MyWidget2> {
  //accessing it inside the other class 
  int counter2 = MyWidget.counter;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Comment: but my variable of the first widget or pointpage is inside the state if I try to use it with your method it tells me "The getter 'points' isn't defined for the type 'pointspage'.
"

Comment: do you want to pass the variable from one class to another class?

Comment: or a variable that  can be accessed in both class (you can make it global)

Comment: Would making it global allow me to use it however I like?

Comment: yes you will be able to access it anywhere

Comment: like this prefs.getInt('points')?

Comment: if it is global you can simply access it by calling -- `points`

Comment: I'm new to flutter I don't know how to best use global variables can you give me a practical example?

Comment: just declare it outsite the `StatefulWidget`

Comment: check the code there is a global variable `globalPoints`

Comment: but if I declare it outside the stateful it gives me an error inside the pointspage itself because I use it below the state

Comment: this is becuase you created two `points` variables, remove the one inside the state

Comment: i have one points

Comment: can you show what the error is.

Comment: when I try to import the "points" variable into the cartpage to then be able to use it in an elevatedbutton to be able to subtract the points necessary for the purchase, it gives me this error: "The getter 'points' isn't defined for the type 'pointspage'.
Try importing the library that defines 'points', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'points'"

Comment: you have to import the file that have `points` class inside the `cartpage`

Comment: Could you give me an example, I don't quite understand

Comment: if you are using vscode click on `points ` and press `Ctrl + .`  and it will give you option to import the file

Comment: have you seen the `imports` at the top of the page?

Comment: yeah they are all there

Comment: the only option it gives me is "create field points"

Comment: suppose your app name is `myApp` and the file that have the `points` class name is 'myPoints.dart' you have to import it like `import 'package:myApp/myPoints.dart`

Comment: It's already there but nothing changes

Comment: the name of your class is `points`  and the name of the variable is also `points` , change one of them

Comment: done, but why? it doesn't work the same